# MainActivity is Broken after upgrading Cordova version to 5.1.1

Tags: java, android, cordova

My code was working fine with Corodva version 3.6.4 but after upgrading to 5.1.1 MainActivity throwing many errors.
Below is the code which is working fine with Cordova 3.6.4

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class CordovaApp extends CordovaActivity
{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loadUrl(launchUrl);
   }

   @Override
   public void init() 
   {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     CordovaWebView webView = new CordovaWebView(this);
        CordovaWebViewClient webViewClient;
            webViewClient = new CordovaWebViewClient(this, webView)
            {

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView arg0,
                        String url) 
                {
                    //Log.i("TestApp","URL:" + url);

                    if(url.contains("**"))
                    {
                        url = url.replace("*", "");
                    }

                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(arg0, url);

                }


            };

        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
        this.init(webView, webViewClient, new CordovaChromeClient(this, webView));
   }

}
```

Errors are as follow:

1. Cannot instantiate the type CordovaWebView.
2. CordovaWebViewClient cannot be resolved to a type.

Reason for the error is **CordovaWebViewClient** is reomved in Cordova 4.0.0 and **CordovaWebView** is Interface now.

How can I modify my code so that it will work fine with Cordova 5.1.1?

Comment: Have you been looking for upgrading guidelines on the cordova website? Like here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/upgrade.html

Comment: @Fildor I want to modify init()  method so that it work fine with Cordova 5.1.1.

Comment: Follow the white rabbit. On the site I linked there is instructions on how to deal with WebView.